# Random Callout Timeouts suddenly since today

Tags: callout

I do Callouts within the same org.

Suddenly this morning i got timeout errors at like every second try.
That never happend before, why today and that much?

Why is there a random response, that makes no sence for me.
Either I receive the right response within like 2 seconds or it is timing out after 10 seconds? (ws code not executed) 
I'm quite sure it depends not on the webservice code, since the callout is still the same!

Any equal experiences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
req.setTimeout(120000); // timeout in milliseconds - this is two minute
```

Use the above for  increasing HTTP callout time to poll for response

```
 request inita=new request.ManageCollectionHttpPort();
 inita.timeout_x=120000;
```

use above pattern for increasing time out in WSDL API.

set it to maximum.We never can estimate the response time from the server in webservice call and to be on safer side we should increase the timeout to maximum (2 minutes)

Comment: thanks for your fast resposne :)
That might be a good solution, didn't tried it yesterday and today the server seems to be okay again, no timeouts today. weird..
But I gonna implement it like that for the next bad days..

Answer (score 1):

I would check the webservice and look for logs and load times on the webservice. So if you have logs which would display time taken to read the call out data and process it, it might help. Or check the network for any new firewall rules or tunnel. it could also be reverse proxy which can do this as well..
Buyan